# UnKnown type Exam and UnKnown type AppDelegate error

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Previously [i posted a question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656190/creating-an-object-in-appdelegate-beginner#comment12262484_9656190), without knowing what caused this error. Later i created a new project and re-created the error. Here's what it says;

I am getting an error called Unknown type name `Exam`. I have a question posted under a different heading. But now i found what the problem is (SO i created another question, hope people will not object this move, and provide me a solution to my problem :) )

I created a fresh project to find what went wrong.

I created a `NSObject` class called `Exam`.

in the AppDelegate.h i added the following;

```
  #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Exam.h"
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate>{
   Exam *ex;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;
@property (strong, nonatomic) Exam *ex;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;

@end
```

in AppDelegate.m i have only synthesis `ex`, so i am not pasting that code here.

Now in the Exam class (NSObject class), i have the following code;

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Exam : NSObject {
   AppDelegate*APP; <-- here i get Unknown type AppDelegate.
}

@end
```

As soon as i create the `AppDelegate` object here, i get the errors.

note: I am using ARC

Answer (score 9, accepted):

change **Exam.h** to

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    @class AppDelegate

    @interface Exam : NSObject {
       AppDelegate*APP; <-- here i get Unknown type AppDelegate.
    }

    @end
```

then your **Exam.m** above `@implementation` do this

```
    #import "AppDelegate.h"
// Rest is same
    @implementation ...
```

Currently you are importing Exam.h in Appdelgate.h and AppDelegate.h in Exam.h  ..this makes both the classes import each other before executing itself.. which cause compiler errors..since each class refers to the other..

Comment: Yes, this works. May i know what caused this error. I will mark the question as Accepted in 3 minutes. Thank you

Comment: The error was caused by the mutual reference of the headers to each other. An import means that theader is read first, but if that header then refers to the original, the compiler thinks it has read that already and not visit it. That is why it is preferrable to use @class.